# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: sh() is applicable for argument types while testing AWS CLI commands in Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
$ groovy --version
Groovy Version: 2.4.15 JVM: 1.8.0_171 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Mac OS X
```

I want execute some AWS CLI commands in Groovy, eventually in a Jenkinsfile to run in Jenkins of course.

But for prototyping, I want to code it on my Mac and execute it as a plain Groovy script. So I have this, for example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

def getEBSVolumes(awsRegion) {
  def regions
  if (awsRegion == "all") {
    regions = sh(returnStdout: true, script: """#!/usr/bin/env bash
                   aws ec2 describe-regions --output text|awk '{print \$3}'
                 """
                )
  }
  else {
    regions = awsRegion
  }
  echo "Regions: regions"
}

getEBSVolumes("all")
```

When I execute it, I get

```
$ ./x.groovy 
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: x.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[returnStdout:true, script:#!/usr/bin/env bash
                   aws ec2 describe-regions --output text|awk '{print $3}'
                 ]]
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: x.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[returnStdout:true, script:#!/usr/bin/env bash
                   aws ec2 describe-regions --output text|awk '{print $3}'
                 ]]
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
    at x.getEBSVolumes(x.groovy:9)
    at x$getEBSVolumes.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at x.run(x.groovy:20)
```

Can someone please explain the cryptic error message? Thanks!

Note the code works when executed in a Jenkinsfile, hence I specifically asked about CLI Groovy.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You wont be able to run this script locally with Groovy only, because it fails due to missing `sh` method in your script. This `sh` method is a step provided by Jenkins Pipeline DSL library - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#code-sh-code-shell-script

I would suggest you running your local Jenkins - the easiest way to do it is to use an existing Docker image. I use for example following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
jenkins:
  image: jenkins:2.60.3-alpine
  container_name: jenkins
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  volumes:
    - ./home:/var/jenkins_home
```

and whenever I want to run my local Jenkins I just go the directory where I have this file stored, e.g.

```
cd ~/workspace/jenkins
```

and I simply call

```
docker-compose up -d
```

which boots Jenkins I can access via http://localhost:8080 In this local instance I am able to test pipeline scripts inside Groovy Sandbox or by setting up a scripted pipeline.

#### Alternative: JenkinsPipelineUnit testing library

If you want to unit test your pipeline scripts you can use [JenkinsPipelineUnit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/JenkinsPipelineUnit) library which allows you to unit test the flow of your pipeline. However in this case you would have to register your own `sh` method, because the `BasePipelineTest` class mocks it with NOOP:

```
helper.registerAllowedMethod("sh", [Map.class], null)
```

It means that each interaction with `sh` step gets counted but it does not trigger the script defined with `script: ''` property.

I would say that setting up your own local Jenkins sandbox where you can play around with Jenkinsfile scripts is the easiest way to start with.

Comment: Thanks, I'll setup my Jenkins sandbox indeed.

Comment: When go to localhost:8080, it tells me to get the secret from /var/jenkins_home, but that folder is not there since root owns /var and it's 0755. So I restart the whole process and set ./home in the yml file to /Users/myuser/jenkins_home, and see NO files there either? Even then, the message in localhost:8080 still tells me to got the /var/jenkins_home?

Comment: In my case container's `/var/jenkins_home` is mounted to `~/workspace/jenkins/home` (docker-compose file is located in `~/workspace/jenkins` folder). I don't remember if I had to create this `home` directory manually or if I had to change permissions to this folder while it got created, but I would try creating it and setting permissions if needed.

Comment: Got it to work, thanks! I followed you suggestion exactly.

Comment: New to docker. How do I add AWS CLI in the docker-compose.yml file? Or any package for that matter?

Comment: The simplest way might be to use an image that provides AWS CLI directly, e.g. https://hub.docker.com/r/dalekurt/jenkins-awscli/ this one

Comment: Thanks. So in your yml example, instead of using jenkins:2.60.3-alpine I use dalekurt/jenkins-awscli for the image?

Comment: `jenkins:2.60.3-alpine` image is deprecated. I think `jenkins/jenkins:latest` would be the replacement

Comment: Don't forget to install the correct plugins

Comment: it asks for plugins!

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the answer by @Szymon-Stepniak -- once you have a jenkins instance running

- New item
- Type: pipeline (may be dependent on Pipeline: Job / Pipeline: Groovy plugins)
- configure pipeline script